# BlackBerry Update Site for Mac Broken?

Tags: eclipse, blackberry

I was setting up the BlackBerry Development environment on my MacBook Pro. I downloaded and installed the entire Eclipse package with the plugin from here:

https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/java/download/eclipse

Over here is says that we can use the update site at http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/mac/java to install different versions of the API, but this site doesn't work. Eclipse can't find anything there, and visiting it from a browser returns a 404.

Is there any other site where I can get the platforms for the Mac from?

Comment: This question is [on-topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61730/154004), please add a gist of your solution in your answer (in case you can't pay your website hosting bills :P )

Comment: @Reno Yeah. My site seems to have broken right now :P I'll add a gist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I got it working with a few changes in the windows SDK. I'm detailed, step by step, instructions below incase anyone else runs into the same problem:

To start with, point a tab in your browser to `https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/java/download/eclipse?os=mac` and download the full Eclipse + Plugin installer. This is a large download (~350MB) and will take a while to complete. After downloading it, run the installer to finish the installation.

Now read through the entire page to see what RIM recommends you do next, and carefully proceed to ignore it. The installer you ran will only give you the 7.0 Platform SDK. if you want to target a larger audience, you will want to install the other SDKs as well. The method using the update site given on that page will not work, as that update site no longer exists, and RIM has failed to update the instructions.

Instead, follow the instructions I give you here. In Eclipse, go to `Help -> Install New Software`. In the box that opens, click the `Add…` button and add a site with any name you like and the following URL: `http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/java`.
Once you add it, a list of software should come in the box below it. Select all of the platform levels you want to install and start the install process. All of them have relatively large downloads, so wait for some time. Once all of them have installed, you will realize that this is all Windows software. Now don’t panic. Do the following to get it working on your Mac:

Start the process of creating a new BlackBerry project and then click the configure JREs link in the JRE part.

[image]

**Configure JREs**

Now open the finder, and navigate to the location of your Eclipse install. Go to the Plugins folder, and locate the folder with the SDK you want to add. It should have a name like `net.rim.ejde...`, with the version of the SDK given in it. Open the components folder and then open the BlackBerry.ee file in your favorite text editor. Now replace some of the lines with their counterparts that I give below:

```
-Dee.executable=${ee.home}/simulator/fledge.exe
-Dee.bootclasspath=${ee.home}/lib/net_rim_api.jar
-Dee.javadoc=file:${ee.home}/docs/api
-Dee.language.level=1.3
-Djava.home=${ee.home}
```

Save the file. Now replace the `components/bin` folder with the one in the 7.0 SDK’s components folder. Now go back to the JRE management dialog in Eclipse and Click add JRE. Select the `BlackBerry.ee` file you edited and click Finish.

Your new SDK is now ready. Repeat these steps until all of your SDKS have been setup.